# navbar se ve distinta en Chrome y Firefox

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Desarrollo una app web Responsive con Bootstrap y se visualiza distinto en Chrome; he probado en IExplorer y Mozilla y se ve correctamente, comprobé errores en Chrome con <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> y no arroja ninguno

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!---   -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx"><span>
                        <!---   -->
                        <img alt="Logo" src="Imagenes/Logo.png" height="30" /></span>&nbsp;<strong> LOGO </strong></a><!---   -->
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <!---   -->
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <!---   -->
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Productos<b class="caret"></b></a><!---   -->
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!---   -->
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Menú 1</li>
                                <!---   -->
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <!---   -->
                                <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                                <!---   -->
                                <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Menú 2</li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cosas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Registro</a></li>
                        <!---   -->

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Borra temporales, aveces chrome se queda pegado

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Puedo responderlo? para que lo marques como respuesta correcta?

Comment: Claro que si, espero la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces ciertas pruebas en chrome y luego haces modificaciones a tu codigo, en chrome se quedan pegadas por lo tanto tienes que borrar temporales (Historial) e incluso despues de realizar esta acción sigue igual pero luego ya no, esto seria una respuesta algo absurda pero correcta